# How to get part of an array object?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I am attempting to get a part of an array. I have `$message["attachment[0]` that when I put into a `file_put_contents` an array outputs. A `[name]` object is part of the array.

However, in the code below, when I try to access only the `[name]`, an error produces. I'm sure it is because of the way I'm calling it. `$message["attachment[0][name]"]`. I don't know how else I can call it.

Does anyone know how I can get the `[name]` of `$message["attachment[0]]`?

```
$message["attachment[0]"] = curl_file_create($target_dir . $filename[0] . ".zip",
    pathinfo("uploads/{$filename[0]}.zip", PATHINFO_EXTENSION),
    $filename[0] . ".zip");

    file_put_contents('file_attachment_log', "\n[{$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}]" . print_r($message["attachment[0]"], true), FILE_APPEND);
    $out = "<a href='/php/" . $message["attachment[0]"] ."'>{$filename}</a>";
```

The file_put_contents generates:

```
[2019-10-29 15:52:15]CURLFile Object
(
    [name] => uploads/airport.jpg.zip
    [mime] => zip
    [postname] => airport.jpg.zip
)
```

Comment: I would use json_encode and put that in your file and when you read it back in do json_decode and it will be back to an object.

Comment: Have you tried direct access to the `name` property, ex: `$myvar->name` ?

Comment: @ka_lin Thanks that did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be like you can just get it with:

```
$message["attachment[0]"]->name;
```

Does this not work?

Comment: Sam once it saves to the file it is just plain text, no longer an object.